# Django Fullcalendar - More than one calendar in App

Tags: django, fullcalendar, django-3.0

Sice i managed to implement Fullcalendar's functionality into my Django app, I have another question.

Is it possible to render more than one Fullcalendar into my html page, depending of how many Calendars are made inside the database. And, i need them to be rendered HORIZONTALLY.

I suppose that i need to change my div's id to 'calendar2' for example. But what should i change inside the initializer?

```
This is full script and style from my calendar.

<script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    minTime: "07:00:00",
                    maxTime: "22:00:00",
                    businessHours: {
                        startTime: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                        endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                    },
                    height: 'auto',
                    locale: 'sr',
                    plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                    defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
                    header: {
                        left: 'today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                    },
                    navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                    editable: false,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: [
                        {% for i in events %}
                            {
                                title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                                start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.start_date|time:"H:i" }}',
                                end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',

                            },
                        {% endfor %}
                    ]
                });
                calendar.render();
            });
</script>

<style>

            body {
                margin: 40px 10px;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            #calendar {
                max-width: 900px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

</style>

<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
```

Comment: "Is it possible to render more than one Fullcalendar into my html page"...yes, just create as many `div` elements as you need, and attach a calendar to each one (`let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');` controls which element the calendar is attached to, so you just need that to be dynamic, or repeated). " i need them to be rendered HORIZONTALLY"...that's down to whatever CSS you use to position the `div` elements, nothing to do with fullCalendar really. Maybe you could use floats or flexbox for that, for example.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i needed!
@ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll pass the answer from the comment section.

Just create as many div elements as you need, and attach a calendar to each one (let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar'); controls which element the calendar is attached to, so you just need that to be dynamic, or repeated).

And flex style helped me to put the next to each other, horizontally